# Question about Objective-C selectors; Can I use parameters and how?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, cocos2d-iphone, selector

I'm attempting to use a selector with arguments and failing while doing so. I'm coming from C/++ and selectors are a tad bit confusing. I have this code:

```
playItem = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:playLabel target:self selector:@selector(goToScene:)argumentHere];
```

How would I go about passing an argument to a method in this way?

Thanks in advance:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Selectors specify only method to be invoked, not parameters to be passed.

What you can do, is to check `sender` parameter in your `goToScene:` method. It's gonna be the element on which action is performed (most probably `CCMenuItemLabel` in your case).
Thus, you can see which element was invoked (if you use `goToScene:` for several ui elements) and decide which 'parameter' to use.

To tell different ui elements apart, `tag` attribute is often used. So, code could look like

```
if ([sender tag] == 1) {
    ...
} else if ...
```

If you don't like too many ifs, lookup table will work.

Comment: Dang. Well, okay then. I wanted to know because I thought it would be easier to make one method then pass which scene I want to switch to rather than make one method per scene. Thanks

Comment: @epicasian You can make one method per scene and from them call a generic method with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking for `performSelector:withObject`? I'm afraid I don't quite understand your questions maybe.

Nikita is right, when you are setting up the selector you just pass in the descriptor name. Later in your code, when you call the method, you will pass in any arguments.